# Как узнать Username в Телеграм зная ID с помощью бота?

Tags: telegram-bot, telegram

Пробовал нескольких ботов они прекрасно определяют ID по Username. У меня обратная задача, есть ID в Телеграм нужно получить Username.

Comment: Пожалуйста, исправьте вопрос, чтобы он отражал конкретную проблему с достаточным количеством деталей для возможности дать адекватный ответ.

Comment: Какую библиотеку используете?